# How to create web deployment package from team build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build, msdeploy

I've been reading and experimenting for days. I bought the latest "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine - Using MSBUild and Team Foundation Build". I've been trying to figure things out by looking at the build targets.

I was quickly able to get a package to be built on the build server, but I want to be able to specify the installation folder, so it doesn't go into wwwroot. I read that I would have to switch the project over from using cassini to the local IIS server. Went through all of that.

The args I'm passing to msbuild through the definition:

/p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=InProc /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=localhost

I've got SO MANY questions, but I'll start simply. If anyone can provide guidance I'd be super thankful.

1. If the named application doesn't exist on the build server (which it shouldn't!) the package creation fails. If I add a shell app named accordingly the package is built.
2. Even if I hack my way past #1 when I try to deploy using Web.deploy.cmd, it fails:

   Error: Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider appHostConfig is not supported.

   Note that the build server is 64-bit and THIS target server (development) is 32-bit. I have the build configuration building against "any cpu". Oh, and I'm invoking the deployment FROM the 32-bit machine, so there's only the 32-bit msdeploy.exe available.

Answer (score 1):

In the appropriate BuildDefinition under "Process", expand the "Advanced" section and set the value of "MSBuild Arguments" to "/p:DeployOnBuild=True".

That will make your WebDeploy Package built according to your settings in the project properties.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that I was using that approach. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I write 2 articles about how to create Web Package and auto deploy it to a Web Server, I think it maybe useful for you.

Auto Deploy your Website for QA with Team Build [click here](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/auto-deploy-your-website-for-qa-with-team-build/)

How to run remote deploy with MS Deploy? [click here](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/how-to-run-remote-deploy-with-ms-deploy/)

Comment: After spending a few days trying to get this going it became super obvious that msdeploy wasn't going to be useful to us. The only thing it offers over xcopy is creating the web site. In order to do THAT, you need to specify that it should copy the IIS settings. Fine, but to do THAT when using the build server, the web site needs to be set up on the build server. Just useless. If I could have figured out how to generate the deployment script and the parameter files I could have spit the packages out for each of the environments during the team build and used them with TFS Deployer.

Comment: But even then ... why go through all that effort when xcopy delivers 99% of the functionality we need. I could understand if we were deploying sites daily, but we have a handful of projects and there's simply no way to justify the amount of effort required into getting this to work for us. It's another example of how - out of the box it does a great job on surface, but trying to tweak it a bit quickly proves to be a nightmare.